# Is there a name for a data type which can be one of a set?

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for a data value which can only be one of a number of items in a set?

For example, a boolean could be described as a xxxx with possible values of [True,False]. The state of matter could be described as a xxxx with the possible values [Solid,Liquid,Gas]. Size could be [XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL]

I know it's not really a primitive data type - it's a sort of meta-type. The actual value stored is the value of the item in the set. But I want a word for 'something which is always one of a given set'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be thinking of an *enumerated type*. These are present in many programming languages.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the idea. Thanks Kake_Fisk